# How to inject protocol with associated types?

Tags: swift, protocols, solid-principles, associated-types

I have created a protocol as

```
protocol DataBaseManager{
    associatedtype type
    init()
    func insert(object obj: [type])
    func getObject(ofType type: type.Type)-> Array<type>
    //...

}
```

Now i have defined a RealmManager as

```
class RealmManager: DataBaseManager{

    var realm:Realm!

    required init() {
        do{
            realm =  try Realm()
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func insert(object obj: [Object]) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(obj)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("the error in creation of object is \(error)")
        }
    }

    func getObject(ofType type: Object.Type)-> Array<Object> {
        let objects = realm.objects(type)
        return Array(objects)
    }
    //.....
}
```

The whole point in doing so is to replace database later on To SqliteManager with ease if necessary. For that i am sending the dependency in my viewModel as:

```
  struct LoginViewModel {

    var dbManager:DataBaseManager //error in this line
    init(dbManager: DataBaseManager) {
        //.....
        self.dbManager = dbManager
    }
}
```

and calling it as

```
let loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(dbManager:RealmManager())
```

But i am getting error as

> Protocol 'DataBaseManager' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Since swift doesnot support to inject protocol with associated types. What could be the possible tweak to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try giving a generic type parameter to the LoginViewModel struct and using that instead:

```
struct LoginViewModel<DBM: DataBaseManager> {

    var dbManager: DBM

    init(dbManager: DBM) {
        self.dbManager = dbManager
    }
}
```